# MySQL: Error when running a Windowing query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to execute a WINDOW query which is given below:

```
SELECT 
DATE(ts),
oi, 
avg(oi) OVER(PARTITION BY DATE(ts) )  
FROM bybit_oi_1d_BTCUSD
```

It gives the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY DATE(ts) )  
FROM bybit_oi_1d_BTCUSD LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4
```

Comment: What is the MySQL version? Window functions are supported in 8.0+

Comment: Ah.. I am on 5.7

Answer (score 0):

No Window functions until MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.2